# Java login in other frame only if it is correct

Tags: java, validation, action

Hi I have a code where I register accounts and after let the registered accounts enter my code to use it but for now with ActionPerformed even if the infos aren't valid the code opens the new frame that I want to restrict without an account. I do not know how I can put a condition with my `if e.getSource()`  to only open if the login is valid and nothing else thank you in advance for your help

EDIT: also the frame MathoQuest pops up two at the same time of the same folder I do no know why

here's the code:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(e.getSource()==btsubmit){
         String uname=txtnamereg.getText();
         String passw=new String(txtpasswordreg.getPassword());
         if(!checkBlank(uname,passw, lblnamereg,lblpasswordreg)){
             if(!checkExist("init.txt",uname)){
                 passw=new String(encrypt(passw));
                 String accinfo=uname+"-"+passw;
                 saveToFile("init.txt",accinfo);
             }
         }
     }
     else if(e.getSource()==btlogin){
        String uname=txtname.getText();
        String passw=new String(txtpassword.getPassword());
        if(!checkBlank(uname,passw,lblname,lblpassword))
            validateUser("init.txt",uname,passw);     
     }
     if (e.getSource() == btlogin ) {
         MathoQuest math = new MathoQuest();
         math.getContentPane();
         math.setVisible(true);
     }
   }
```

If you want to see how it validates, I will include here so you can have an idea too:

```
public void validateUser(String filename, String name, String password){
       FileReader fr;
       BufferedReader br;
       boolean valid=false;
       String accinfo;
       try{ 
           fr=new FileReader(filename);
           br=new BufferedReader(fr);
           while ((accinfo=br.readLine())!=null){

               if(check(accinfo,name,password)){

                   showMess("Login valide",lblmess);
                   valid=true;
                   break;                  
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `validateUser` to return a boolean, `true` if the login is valid and `false` otherwise.

Then use the returned information to decide to open or not the frame.

For example:

```
public boolean validateUser(String filename, String name, String password) {
    ...
    if(check(accinfo, name, password)) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
    return false
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
boolean valid = validateUser("init.txt",uname,passw);
if(valid) {
     ...
}
```